Why does Linearity of Expectation not hold regarding this distribution?
I have recently been looking into the probability of dice pools, and looking into a particular system, I noticed something peculiar.
The Revised Storyteller System (used in a number of White Wolf Games in the late 1990s), uses a modified success-based dice pool system using 10-sided dice, where dice rolls obey the following rules:

Each dice that shows 7 or higher counts as a "hit" (the dice counts as a +1 to the roll's score)
If no dice in a roll show 7 or higher (ie there are no "hits") than any dice that show a 1 are considered a "botch", or a negative hit. (which we will consider as a -1 to the roll's score).

It turns out that this is quite simple to model as a piecewise probability distribution as follows (where $n=$ # of dice, and $h=$ # of "hits"):
$$P(H=h)=\begin{cases}
\binom{n}{h}\left ( \frac{4}{10} \right )^h\left ( \frac{6}{10} \right )^{n-h} & \text{ if } h>0 \\
\binom{n}{|h|}\left ( \frac{1}{6} \right )^{|h|}\left ( \frac{5}{6} \right )^{n-h} & \text{ if } h\leq0 
\end{cases}$$
After a bit of work, we can also find the Expectation of this roll:
$$E(H)=\frac{n\left (4-\left (\frac{6}{10}\right )^{n-1} \right )}{10}$$
I notice here that this is not linear with respect to $n$:  $E(nH)\neq nE(H)$. The expectation approaches linearity as $n$ grows (since the power term will shrink to zero exponentially as $n$ increases), but it's not actually linear.
I've been trying to research this and while there's plenty of online work on why the Linearity of Expectation holds with so many probability distributions, I can't seem to find any resources on when Linearity of Expectation doesn't hold. So my question is, why does Linearity of Expectation not hold in this case, and is there a general rule as to when we should expect it not to hold? Alternatively, why am I incorrect about it not holding? What am I missing here?

$nH$ is a random variable that has support $0$, $\pm n$, $\pm 2n, \ldots$. $E(nH) := \sum_{x \in { \pm nh } } x P(nH = x) = n \sum_{x \in { \pm nh } } h P(H = x/n) = nE(H)$.

In particular, $E(nH) = nE(H)$ holds even when $E(H)$ is not a linear function of $n$, as you have noticed.

You are using one symbol "$H$" to refer to many different distributions. For each $n$, you have a different distribution. Instead you could write, for example, $H_n$ for the random variable which arises as the number of "hits" when the number of dice is $n$. Then you can consider $E(H_n)$. I am not sure how you think linearity of expectation applies here, but indeed $E(H_n)$ is not a linear function of $n$.

@JamesMartin I had expected the expectation to be linear because the system here is based on Binomial distributions, where expectations typically are linear. I was mostly curious as to why this system, in particular, deviated from that pattern. Henry's answer below makes sense - this system's expectation isn't a linear function of $n$ because $B_n$ isn't truly independent - there's effectively a "global condition" that can't be built from each die in isolation.

Using @JamesMartin's suggested notation where $H_n$ is the net number of hits with $n$ dice, you have correctly observed that $\mathbb E[H_n] \not = n\,E[H_1]$.
If you split $H_n$ into positive hits $P_n$ and botchs $B_n$ (the absolute value of negative hits - is botches a better spelling?) with $H_n=P_n-B_n$, and so by linearity of expectation $\mathbb E[H_n]=\mathbb E[P_n]-\mathbb E[B_n]$ even though $P_n$ and $B_n$ are not independent, where

$\mathbb E[P_n] = \frac{4n}{10} $ which is linear in $n$, i.e. $\mathbb E[P_n]= n\,\mathbb E[P_1]$
$\mathbb E[B_n] = \left(\frac{6}{10}\right)^n \frac{n}{6}$ which is not linear in $n$, i.e. $\mathbb E[B_n]\not = n\,\mathbb E[B_1]$, principally because we need all $n$ dice to be $6$ or less to get any botchs on any of them and so we cannot simply split the effect of low dice into separate events

implying $\mathbb E[P_n]-\mathbb E[B_n]\not =  n\,\mathbb E[P_1] - n\,\mathbb E[B_1]$ when $n>1$.
